# how to check if a pre-determined sequence of numbers in a column is one by one in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I have a `dataframe`named `mydata` (5x2000141) that has a column named `target_ID` (numeric) which identifies an `ID` (character) for a single `date` (Date) which is associated with a result `R` (numeric). `target_ID` is unique for an `ID` in that specific `date`.
Notes:

- `ID` is repeated several times in the data frame (the same `ID` was measured at different dates).
- `dates` can be the same for different IDs.
- each `target_ID`, `ID` and `date` has specifically 1748 entries `N`, each one of them with the associated result "R".

This is how my data frame `mydata` looks like:

| N | target_ID | ID | date | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a1 | 2011-04-12 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | a1 | 2011-04-12 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | a1 | 2011-04-12 | 3 |
| .... | .. | .. | .... | .. |
| 1748 | 1 | a1 | 2011-04-12 | 5 |
| 1749 | 2 | a2 | 2011-04-12 | 5 |
| 1750 | 2 | a2 | 2011-04-12 | 2 |
| ... | .. | .. | .... | .. |
| 3495 | 2 | a2 | 2011-04-12 | 2 |
| 3496 | 2 | a2 | 2011-04-12 | 4 |
| .... | .. | .. | .... | .. |
| 384560 | 292 | p5 | 2012-03-09 | 9 |
| 384561 | 292 | p5 | 2012-03-09 | 9 |
| .... | .. | .. | .... | .. |
| 386306 | 292 | p5 | 2012-03-09 | 1 |
| 386307 | 292 | p5 | 2012-03-09 | 3 |
| 386308 | 293 | t1 | 2012-03-09 | 3 |
| .... | .. | .. | .... | .. |

My question is the following: I'm trying to check (e.g.:TRUE or FALSE) if in 1748 per 1748 entries the "target_ID" follows an ascending order 1 by 1 value. I used this code: `mydata2 <- mydata %>% group_by(target_ID) %>% summarize(Result = all(diff(target_ID) == 1)) %>% ungroup()` but since I don't have an unique object 1748 per 1748 entries the results does not gives me what I pretend.
I also tried `mydata2 <- mydata %>% group_by(target_ID, date) %>% summarize(Result = all(diff(target_ID) == 1)) %>% ungroup()` but the function `group_by` does not allows two columns.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same single column:

```
df <- data.frame(target_ID = rep(1:292,each = 1748))
```

test for ascending:

```
is.unsorted(rle(df$target_ID)$values)
[1] FALSE # so it is ascending
```

test for consistent length:

```
length(which(rle(df$target_ID)$lengths == 1748))
[1] 292
```

A great compliment to `rle` is `seqle` found in the `cgwtools` package that provides a lenghts\values output but for sequences. In addition to confirming characteristics (is it ascending), combining rle and seqle indexs with `which` logic might get you to nearly unique values.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: construct a desired sequence to compare with your `mydata`, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(target_ID = rep(1:292,each = 1748))
bench.ID <- rep(1:292, each = 1748)
identical(df$target_ID,bench.ID)
```